# DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR without unnecessary rows like EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT or Plan hash value (without using sed or awk)

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using a query looking like this: `SELECT plan_table_output FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL,NULL,'BASIC'));`

The output it gives me looks like this:

```
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(T1 8 ) */   * FROM   T1

Plan hash value: 2494645258

-----------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     |
-----------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR      |          |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |
|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1       |
-----------------------------------------
```

But I want the output like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     |
-----------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR      |          |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 |
|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Without the unnecessary (for me at least) `EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT` and `Plan hash value`.#

Is there any way to do this, without using sed or awk to remove the unnecessary lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to have a nice graphical representation of the execution plan, then use the `EXPLAIN PLAN` window in `Oracle SQL Developer`.

[image]

**EDIT**

**Based on @a_horse_with_no_name solution, tweaking a bit more gives the exact desired output.**

```
SQL> SELECT plan_table_output
  2  FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL,NULL,'BASIC'))
  3  WHERE substr(plan_table_output,1,1) in ('|', '-')
  4  /

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------
----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name |
----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |
----------------------------------

7 rows selected.
```

So, I still see the PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT in the output. Setting pagesize to 0 should take of it.

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> SELECT plan_table_output
  2  FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL,NULL,'BASIC'))
  3  WHERE substr(plan_table_output,1,1) in ('|', '-')
  4  /
------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name           |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| DISPLAY_CURSOR |
------------------------------------------------------------

7 rows selected.
```

Now there is still something unwanted, `------------------------`, let's just not include in the output at all.

```
SQL> SELECT plan_table_output
  2  FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL,NULL,'BASIC'))
  3  WHERE substr(plan_table_output,1,1) in ('|', '-')
  4  and plan_table_output not in('------------------------')
  5  /
------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name           |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| DISPLAY_CURSOR |
------------------------------------------------------------

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your effort, but I forgot to mention that this has to be done under SQL*Plus, I need the output in a txt file, this is for CI purposes and Jenkins can't handle the Oracle SQL Developer ;)

Comment: No problem. @a_horse_with_no_name has a very close answer above.

Comment: I have tweaked his solution a bit and should now provide exact output.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a where condition:

```
SELECT plan_table_output 
FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL,NULL,'BASIC'))
WHERE substr(plan_table_output,1,1) in ('|', '-')
```

This will however not remove some of the "underlines" in the summary section of the output. However you can extend the `where` clause to include more rules

Comment: Thanks! It still leaves a `------------------------` in the first line (I've pasted its exact lenght), but it helped me. Could You leave a small explaination to the line You added? And what could I do to do the exact same thing with the summary section? With the 'BASIC' format there is no summary, but there may come a time when I'll need it...

Comment: The where clause now considers only those parts which has either of `-` or `|` in the plan table output. So, basically what you needed was just the execution plan which definitely starts with either of `-` or `|`, and the solution almost works. Since, `substr(plan_table_output,1,1)` means the first character i.e. `-` or `|`.

Comment: See my edit in the answer.  The output would match your desired output.

Comment: Great thanks both of You! Could You just explain me one line of the query? `WHERE substr(plan_table_output,1,1) in ('|', '-')`, Im talking about the part `substr(plan_table_output,1,1)`

Comment: `substr(plan_table_output,1,1)` will give the first character of each row of the output. See [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679)